# Median function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I tried

```
mtcars <- data.table( mtcars, keep.rownames=T)

mtcars[median(qsec),]

mtcars[order(qsec),]
```

This gives me 15th value though it should have given me the 16 value as the dataset has 32 values in it.

Please help me if I am doing something wrong... I know it's quite the basics

Comment: You need to explain in words, not code, what you are trying to achieve. You want the middle row? You want the row with the `qsec` value closest to the median? Just explain it in text at first, and also, if you say "This gives me the 15th row" then cut and paste that output into your question so we can see it.

Comment: I am trying to find the median of qsec of mtcars...i get the same result chrysler Imperial but i don't think that's the median... Because when i sort the qsec vector chrysler Imperial is the 15th value not the 16 or 17 as it should be

Comment: @Spacedman so hope you can clarify am i wrong somewhere...i am just starting to learn it....

Comment: The median of qsec is a single number, not a particular car. In this case its 17.71. There are 16 cars with qsec less than that, and 16 with qsec greater than that. You are trying to get row number 17.71 of the data, which works only because R rounds it to 17. What you are doing is meaningless. If you did mtcars[median(disp),] you'd be trying to get row number 196.3, because that's the median displacement. There's no row number 196.

Comment: @Spacedman i understood it a little bit... Thanks for the help buddy tomorrow i will try it again afresh... Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: @Spacedman it means i am coding it wrong....i was hoping he would give me the data point of median in the dataset but instead i used median as a row number

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks I got what I needed the median mtcars qsec is  Lincoln Continental... which I will get by  mtcars[order(qsec),][median(qsec),]... I understood that I was feeding wrong data.... Now I understand what does it mean by garbage in garbage out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your `qsec` is, so I'll assume you've attached `mtcars` and its the column from there. PLEASE edit your question and show *ALL* your working so anyone else can get your results. Let's proceed:

```
> attach(mtcars) # WARNING: Attaching data frames is a BAD IDEA
> median(qsec)
[1] 17.71
> mtcars[median(qsec),]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
```

Because the median of `qsec` is 17.7, `mtcars[median(qsec),]` will get row 17.7, which is rounded down to 17:

```
> mtcars[17,]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
```

[I don't know why you say 16, maybe you've filtered `mtcars` or something, I can't reproduce your work because you've not shown your working.]

So what were you trying to do? Get the row where `qsec` is the median value of its values? Well you can do that, but its pretty pointless because there's no guarantee that the median of a set of values will be one of the values. So if you try this you get nothing:

```
> mtcars[qsec==median(qsec),]
 [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

i.e. there are no rows where `qsec` equals its median value.

Comment: mtcars<-data.table(mtcars,keep.rownames=T)


mtcars[median(qsec),]


mtcars[order(qsec),]

Comment: These are the 3 lines that I use... But when I order mtcars to qsec it gives me 15th row. it should have given me 17 or 16th row